# Intercept the paginated response in hotchocolate

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I have 2 separate collections one which stores all users and the other which has all the details and metadata. I am having an endpoint in hotchocolate which gives a paginated response of users details. Querying the user collection and having it as a static list is inexpensive so what I need to do is get the paginated list of ids of user when the endpoint  is called so that I can get the details of only the ids requested by the endpoint. Is something like this doable ?

Comment: It depends on how you declaring schema types, but anyway [a resolver](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/resolvers) is what you need